# Why do I get `AddressAlreadyInUse` for an unused local host/port combo after a `ConnectionRefused`?

Tags: .net, sockets

When connecting to a host/port where no server is listening, I get `ConnectionRefused`, which is fine. However, when retrying in 1 minute intervals to the (meanwhile started) server, I get `AddressAlreadyInUse`.

This seems to be due to binding to the same host/ip combo. But the port is not used, netstat does not show anything, not even a TIME_WAIT state or anything that would yield `AddressAlreadyInUse`. So what is causing this?

The code goes something like this:

```
var bindEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(192.168.60.60, 55001);
var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(192.168.50.54, 55001);

while (true)
{
  try
  {
    log("Connecting to " + endPoint + " from " + bindEndPoint);
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.Bind(bindEndPoint);
    socket.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 0);
    socket.Connect(endPoint);
    log("Connection succeeded");
    DoStuffAsLongAsConnected();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    log("Connection failed: Socket Error " + e.ErrorCode + " " + e.SocketErrorCode + Environment.NewLine + e);
  }
  Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000);
}
```

The logs:

```
14:37:42.581 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:37:43.597 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10061 ConnectionRefused
14:38:43.428 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:39:44.243 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:39:44.243 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:40:45.155 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:40:45.155 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:41:46.083 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:41:46.083 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:42:46.561 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:42:46.561 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:43:46.904 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:43:46.904 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:44:47.309 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:44:47.309 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:45:47.698 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:45:47.698 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:46:48.087 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:46:48.087 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:47:48.673 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:47:48.673 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:48:49.331 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:48:49.331 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:49:50.036 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:49:50.036 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection failed: Socket Error 10048 AddressAlreadyInUse
14:50:50.662 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connecting to 192.168.50.54:55001 from 192.168.60.60:55001
14:50:50.662 192.168.60.60:55001->192.168.50.54:55001 Connection succeeded
```

Comment: I don't think netstat would show a connection that was never established so that makes sense. Your while should only include the connect call and not the recreation of the socket as you never release it by calling close on it, just trying to recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the exception in `Connect()`, I have to call `.Dispose()` on the existing `Socket` before creating a new one and bind it to the same local ip/port, then no `AddressAlreadyInUse` exceptions get thrown.

@o_weisman Thanks for the hint - reusing the existing `Socket` is perhaps another option.